# Can we Use MVVMLight for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, mvvm-light

I am new to Xamarin. I want to implement MVVM pattern. My question is, Can we use MVVM light for Xamarin iOS and Android projects ?

Comment: PLease elaborate your question --SO reviews

Answer (score 3):

MvvmLight is available as version 5.3.0 in Nuget. https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight/

It should work for iOS and Android amongst others.